# Why is "enable android banner" missing from my Unity Player settings for Android?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I have a googlevr project in Unity that I build for android.

I need to either enable or change the "Android Banner"

This option, as denoted in the manual as being in the player settings https://answers.unity.com/questions/936577/player-settings-icon-enable-android-banner.html Does not exist for me.

How can I address the android banner in this project? Why would it be missing?

This project's player settings look like this:

[image: No "Enable Android Banner"]

A newly created project with the GoogleVR sdk loaded's player settings look like this(this is how my project should presumably look):

[image: How it should look]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question since this isn't documented very well!  In that same android player settings window you must first check the "*Android TV Compatibility*" box under "*Other Settings > Configuration*".  Once you check that box, the "*Enable Android Banner*" will show up for you under "*Icons*".

The box is at the bottom of this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @KinsDotNet Yup! Hopefully this can help some other folks out, too.  I couldn't find any official documentation on this.